# Ruby - variable is incremented in one place, but shows as default in another

Tags: arrays, ruby, global-variables

I declare $a, and later, in the loop, I increment it and then pass it to widget, however, when I look at the output widget is generating, $a is perpetually 1. How can I get the math stored in the array to work with the loop-incremented $a?

Please excuse the newbie code smell- also, this is a very dumbed-down version of what I am building, which is an attempt at solving Project Euler #128

```
    $a = 1
    $arr = Array.new
    $step1 = [1, $a-1, -1]
    $step2 = [$a+6, -5, 2]

    def widget(t,u,v)
        t.each do |math|
            $arr.push (v+math)/u
        end
    end
    (1..100).each do |num|
        if num % 2 == 0
            $a += 1
        end
    if [something]
        widget($step1,$a,num)
    elsif [something else]
        widget($step2,$a,num)
    end
```

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried using instance variables, instead of global variables? No idea if it would work, just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of global variable makes pretty difficult to read the code, but I noted that `$step1` and `$step2` are evaluated before any `$a` increment, so their value is effectively a constant, computed with $a == 1:

```
$step1 = [1, 0, -1] # [1, (1)-1, -1] 
$step2 = [7, -5, 2] # [(1)+6, -5, 2]
```

If this is not the desired behaviour, then you should move these two statements immediately before `if [something]` or transform step1 and step2 from global variables to functions.

Comment: Ah! I see! gee, that was easy. It's working right now that I moved the arrays. Yes, sorry for all the globals. I will take a proper coding class someday soon, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that declaring a variable that equals some operation on another variable uses the current value of that variable.

```
a = 1
  # => 1
b = a
  # => 1
a = 2
  # => 2
puts b
  # => 1
```

The `b` variable doesn't hold "the value of `a`" as a placeholder of sorts, it holds the **current** value of `a` at the time `b` is initialized: 1.

You need to revalue the `$step1` and `$step2` variables right before you use them in order to take the current value of `$a` into account.

OR

You could instead write methods, `step1` and `step2` which both take `$a` as a parameter, and return an array based on the current value of `$a`.